# I want extend CAT5 cable, more than 100m

Tags: networking, switch, local-area-network, cat5, rj45

I have a track like 130 meters. CAT5 cable limit is 100m. Is it possible to cut it in half and get a switch in the middle of the track? Will it work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have 100m long cables between network switches. So this will work.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum length from two end machines  cable length should be with in 100 meters.You cannot extend that without help of any type of accelerator devices like repeter or switches or hub.Above 100 meter there will be attenuation.So the best way you can use a hub or a switch and then connect to next end device.

Comment: as all above told, stop at 99 meters, put a switch between and continue for 99 meters - and repeat as long as you want

Comment: for single connection you can use nrmally 90 meters upto RJ jack.And then 5 meter cable to RJ jack to PC/Device.Here you can use  upto 99 meters single stretch and then put switch then you can extend next 100 meter  cable.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed possible.

The switch will act as a repeater in that case.

I have used a similar solution many years ago to provide internet to a campsite located on a field with nearest neighbour with Internet located at a farm 300 m away.

First option we tried was WiFi with a directional antenna, but it was hard getting a signal to the camp when you dont have line of sight from the farm to campsite, due to a small forest in between and a small difference in altitude between farm and campsite.

The signal was strong enough for the first 1000 m, but the tricky part was getting the antenna pointing in the right direction, both in horizontal and vertical plane.

We fell back to lay out CAT 5 cable between farm and campsite and placed 2 switches in between as repeaters.

I have large tried WiFi at another site with 800 m between antennas and line of sight without any issues - except for no signal in **heavy rainfall**.

My recommendation:

Depending on what gear and/or budget you have my order of priority from best to worst would be:

1) Optical cables for the track.
2) WiFi with directional antennas. Especially if you have line of sight.
3) Cat 5 cables with a switch in between.